# How to transfer complex classes in web api 2 without using extensions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm a tadbit unsure on how complex classes can be transfreed in web api 2.
Almost every example I find is about the old json post class (which no longer exists). For the new Version I don't find that much. Especially when it Comes to complex classes. Almost all of These examples use extensions like the NewtonSoft... .

So my question is: For the example below is there any way (aside from putting a converter into the class that transforms it into a string and back into a class from a string) to Transfer it in a post without having to rely on extensions?

**Server example:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeviceConnect([FromBody]MyDevice device)
{
     ...... // device is to be used and should be transferred from the client
}
```

**Client example:**

```
var cont = new MyDevice();

HttpResponseMessage rb = await client.PostAsync(@"http://localhost:34326/Api/Updater", cont);
```

What I tired already (and naturally failed as it would only convert the Name of the class):

```
var a1= new MyDevice("MyTestDevice", "a");
var cont = new StringContent(a1.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

**MyDevice has the following layout:**

```
public class MyDevice
{
    private EnumClient _Client;
    private string _Office;
    private string _DeviceNumber;    
    private List<InstalledProgram> _InstalledPrograms;


    public List<InstalledProgram> InstalledPrograms{ get => _InstalledPrograms; set => _InstalledPrograms= value; }
    public string DeviceNumber { get => _DeviceNumber; set => _DeviceNumber = value; }
    public EnumClient Client { get => _Client; set => _Client = value; }
    public string Office { get => _Office; set => _Office = value; }

}
```

InstalledPrograms has only a few properties (string Name, string Version).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you are serializing your class to send as `StringContent`. You need to serialize it as a json string instead of just using the `ToString` method. The code below uses the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.

```
var cont = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a1), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: so using an extension like newtonsoft.json is almost a must?

Comment: You could roll your own json serializer, but with the available libraries like Newtonsoft it doesn't make sense to do so.